# Definition of “infix” in formal languages

Tags: formal-languages, terminology

I've got a simple question:

Let's say we have the following definition of a language over some alphabet: $L = \{w \mid w \text{ contains the infix } aab\}$

Does that mean $aab \in L$? or does "$aab$" have to be "wrapped" on both sides by other letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $A$ is the alphabet, then $L = A^*aabA^*$.

Now, what about terminology?
Lothaire in the [first chapter](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Eberstel/Lothaire/lo1.ps) of his book *Combinatorics on words* gives the following definitions. A word $v \in A^*$ is said to be a *factor* of a word $x \in A^*$ if there exist words $u, w \in A^*$ such that $x = uvw$. A factor is *proper* if $v \not= x$.

In my opinion, the word *infix* is also perfectly fine, since it gives a natural counterpart to *prefix* and *suffix*. Terms involving "sub" like *subword* and *substring* are also frequently used in the literature. I personally prefer to follow Lothaire and say that a word $v \in A^*$ is a *subword* of a word $x \in A^*$ if $v = a_1a_2 \cdots a_n$ (where $a_i \in A$ and $n \geqslant 0$) and there exist $y_0, ..., y_n \in A^*$ such that $x = y_0a_1y_1a_2 \cdots a_ny_n$. This definition makes the term *subword* a synonym of *subsequence*, which I find quite natural.

Anyway, with so many different terminology around, it is not a bad idea to remind the reader of precise definitions if there is any risk of ambiguity...

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to ask my teacher for his exact meaning.

Comment: The word infix seemd used more often to qualify a string representation of operator-operand tree (aka terms of a free algebra). Prefix (resp. suffix) notation places the operand before (resp. after) its arguments. Infix notation places the operator between arguments, which may raise ambiguity problems, addressed in various ways.